# "Select badge to track" modal goes off-screen

Tags: bug, design, badge-progress

- Resolution: 1280x720
- Browser: Firefox 68.01
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Problem description:  The "select your next badge" modal goes off-screen and the bottom can't be viewed.

[image: off-screen modal]

Comment: Maybe there's no interest in supporting 720p, though.

Comment: If the browser window is small (short) enough, then the dialog extends off the screen with no scroll bars to see the bottom.